# Setting bounds on different sized google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using a custom ImageMapType as a floorplan. I have to be able to display the same map in two different canvas sizes for use in a responsive website.

The issue I'm having is that when I set the bounds based on the larger version (800x450) of the map, these bounds are incorrect in the smaller version (560x360). The edges of the map are cropped off using on the smaller map using these bounds. Clearly I need to use different (larger) bounds for the small map so the edges are correct.

Is there some way of translating the bounds from the larger map to the smaller one based on the size of the canvas ?

See the Fiddle link below for a demonstration of the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/khendar/CvCMq/1/

```
var marker;
var typeOptions = {
getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
    return 'http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs4/i/2004/267/a/4/The_Middle_Earth_Map_by__electra_.jpg';
},
tileSize: new google.maps.Size(1192, 930),
maxZoom: 5,
minZoom: 5
};
var mapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(typeOptions);
var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
new google.maps.LatLng(-15.076764665951556, 47.2412109375),
new google.maps.LatLng(6.790762250562566, 64.2041015625));

function initialize(canvas) {

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-15.076764665951556, 47.2412109375);
var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 5,
    streetViewControl: false,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ['stores']
    }
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(canvas), mapOptions);
map.mapTypes.set('stores', mapType);
map.setMapTypeId('stores');
lastValidCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-15.076764665951556, 47.2412109375);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function (event) {
    document.getElementById('center').value = map.getCenter();
    if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
        lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
        return;
    }
      map.panTo(lastValidCenter);

});
}
```

Comment: What are your desired bounds?  How did you determine them? If they include all the area you want visible, that area should be visible on both your maps. Please provide details if that is not the case.

Comment: The bounds are the edges of the image I am using as a floorplan. I am setting the boundaries using a tool I created for the purpose. I'd line up the SW and NE corners of the map and save the center positions at each point to be used as the bounds. I'm guessing this is the source of my problems, as the center is going to be further from or closer to the bounds depending on the size of the canvas but I'm not aware of another way of doing it.

I've added a fiddle in the original post to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I figured that using the Center was causing my issues, so I changed it to use map.getBounds() to set the bounds using the NE and SW corners of the viewport, and then compare NE and SW corners and check to see if they are in my map bounds.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function (event) {
    if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getBounds().getSouthWest()) && 
           allowedBounds.contains(map.getBounds().getNorthEast())) {
        lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
        return;
    }
      map.panTo(lastValidCenter);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/khendar/CvCMq/5/

Comment: I would...but I have to wait 24 hours apparently.